# Animated movie about a card game that came to life

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

While thinking about old movies and shows me an my cousin watched as kids, we remembered an animated movie that had a bunch of school kids who had this card game come to life. And ***no*** it was not *Yu-Gi-Oh!*.

In the movie, the characters and monsters in the card game the high school kids possesed started to come to life. The characters were anime characters and one of the boys had blue hair, and *maybe* was a prince of an alien planet in the game. I think an alien invasion started because of the cards and started abducting cows, turning them into monsters of sorts.

It was aired on either Cartoon Network, Nickelodeon or Disney channel. We watched it roughly 2012-2013 and I think the name had "Zero" in it.

Comment: I took the liberty of tagging this with `anime` since it's a common trope among those. Other than that, could you maybe take a look at [these guidelines on ID questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] in? For instance, when did you watch that, more or less? Was it a standalone movie or could it have been a "special episode that lasts twice the usual time" thing from a show? Stuff like that, to increase the chances of a successful ID. Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

After hours of brainstorming, we finally found the movie. *[Exchange Student Zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_Student_Zero)* was its name.

> John Stitt and Max Cameron are two boys fanatical for the card game "Battle Day Zero". One day the combination of a wild storm and a mysterious booster pack suddenly means they can bring Hiro, one of the game's characters into their world. Excited but worried their secret will be discovered, the boys decide to take Hiro to school where he is mistaken for a Japanese exchange student. Despite this temporary solution the portal being open means that more people and monsters from Hiro's world can travel to Earth, wreaking havoc on the small town. the boys decide in order to get things back to normal they must send Hiro back but not before their school dance is overrun with Battle Day Zero characters.

### Trailer

Comment: Glad you found it! It's not useless at all since it will help others looking for the same thing :) don't forget to self-accept your answer by clicking on the checkmark in the left, under the voting buttons; this will show everyone that the mystery was solved! You should be able to do so in ~40 hours. Please do!