# Cartoon movie. Something about an anime/game character coming to real life. He used cards to summon dragons or something

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, dragons

I remember watching it in the early 2010s. From what I remember, the protagonist was very energetic and had spiky hair, probably red, and also a sword nail. He was welcomed by a family, as if he were an exchange student.

He used cards and I remember that in the movie he summoned a dragon with them or something like that. On the cards, there was no dueling system, he just took the card and summoned a monster.

As I recall, at the end of the film he ends up becoming king of the prom or whatever.

I also remember that there was a commercial on Cartoon Network in which he appeared wearing a suit and a crown.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Do you remember roughly when you watched this? And can you recall any additional details, like any other characters involved in the story?

Comment: Were the cards used in dueling (and dealt on a portable "table" surface the characters wore on a forearm)?

Answer (score 3):

I found it, the name is: [*Exchange Student Zero*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3093986/). I messed up a lot of things in my memory but I found it.

Comment: If ever accepted, this would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/195314/animated-movie-about-a-card-game-that-came-to-life