# Show where a kid uses cards to summon demons/characters

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember a show where the protagonist would use cards to summon supernatural characters. I don’t remember a lot but I believe he also befriended one of the demons and used him to summon other demons.

I remember a scene where they released an evil demon at their school and were trying to stop it. I remember watching it on TV, most likely Cartoon Network

**Update: after i posted this answer i did some digging, the show i was looking for was called exchange student zero**

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you watch this?  Do you happen to remember the name of the main character or any of the demons?  Was the setting modern world or something else?

Comment: "cards to summon supernatural characters", "cartoon network" - Sounds like Yu-Gi-Oh

Comment: or Ben 10 maybe? Not sure if they actually used cards but definitely a lot of loose/befriending demons.

Comment: @Sehij Toor - Thank you for providing the answer, but we prefer answers to be posted as answers (via the 'Your Answer' field), rather than being edited into the question. If you don't choose to post the answer as an actual answer, another user likely will, and they'll consequently earn the upvotes and increased reputation score that could've gone to you.

Comment: @Sehij Toor - If you or someone else does post an answer, we'd also appreciate it if you'd mark the answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which is this site's way of showing that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction. You can mark an answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark on the left side of the answer, however, if you post the answer yourself, you'll need to wait until 48 hours have elapsed since the question was first posted.

Comment: I went ahead and posted an answer, but feel free to copy any or all of my answer for your own, Sehij, and then I can delete mine.

Comment: Also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/195314/animated-movie-about-a-card-game-that-came-to-life?rq=1, which is a self-answer.

Comment: I have closed the question as a Duplicate, but that doesn't mean it's a bad question, just one that's been answered before, and we like to tie the entries together in the database. You're still good with accepting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The querent edited into their question that the work they were seeking was the 2012 *[Exchange Student Zero](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4224586/)*. It [has a TV Tropes page](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/ExchangeStudentZero). There was initially a TV movie, and then a series that uses a slightly different continuity in 2015.

[image: Splash page for Exchange Student Zero]

> Two school friends obsessed with a fantasy card game called Battle Day Zero inadvertently bring one of the characters, Hiro, to life. His arrival coincides with that of a Japanese exchange student who he is mistaken for, allowing him to live among the confused townsfolk. The fact that he functions as an anime character in a normal toon world is the source of much confusion and comedy. However, our unlikely heroes manage to keep their new guest's true identity a secret until they can work out how to get him back to his own world. This becomes more difficult when the portal they have opened allows more and more exotic creatures into their sleepy town. Life will never be the same again, and as our leads discover, it is far more exciting this way.

## Trailer